# extract values from column in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
A
url/3gth33/item/PO151302
url/3jfj6/item/S474-3
url/dfhk34j/item/4964114989191
url/sdfkj3k4/place/9b81f6fd
url/as3f343d/thing/ecc539ec
```

I'm looking to extract anything with /item/ and its subsequent value.

The end result should be:

```
item
/item/PO151302
/item/S474-3
/item/4964114989191
```

here is what I've tried:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.extract(r'(/item/\w+\D+\d+$)')
```

This is returning what I need except the integer only values.

Based on the regex docs I'm reading this should grab all instances.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `df['A'].str.extract(r'(/item/[^/]*)')`

Comment: You force having non digits in the regex, so the integers only won't match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/item/.+` to match `/item/` and anything after. Also, if you put `?P<foo>` at the beginning of a group, e.g. `(?P<foo>...)`, the column for that matched group in the returned dataframe of captures will be named what's inside the `<...>`:

```
item = df['A'].str.extract('(?P<item>/item/.+)').dropna()
```

Output:

```
>>> item
                  item
0       /item/PO151302
1         /item/S474-3
2  /item/4964114989191
```

Comment: this works in locating the values I was searching for but dropna() is not dropping the empty rows. I should mention that I have other columns in this dataframe and I'm looking to retain them but remove all the empty rows caused by the regex you supplied above. Let me know what you think.

Comment: What empty rows is `dropna` not removing?

Comment: not sure why but I ended up doing the inverse and I got the result I wanted:
df = df[df["a"].notna()]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a regex solution but it could come handy in some situations.

```py
keyword = "/item/"
df["item"] = ((keyword + df["A"].str.split(keyword).str[-1]) * 
              df["A"].str.contains(keyword))
```

which returns

```sh
                               A                 item
0        url/3gth33/item/PO151302       /item/PO151302
1           url/3jfj6/item/S474-3         /item/S474-3
2  url/dfhk34j/item/4964114989191  /item/4964114989191
3     url/sdfkj3k4/place/9b81f6fd                     
4     url/as3f343d/thing/ecc539ec                     
5
```

And in case you want only the rows where *item* is not empty you could use

```py
df[df["item"].ne("")][["item"]]
```